# How do I put Serializable Objects in a JSON body? In what format should I store in my database?

Tags: java, json, osgi, serializable

I am building a logging/journal service for an osgi framework, with the intention of using my journal entries for restoring the system from a backup after a systemfailure. 
But I came across a problem: to make sure I have enough data, necessary to be able to restore the system correctly, I need to pass used functioncalls and their arguments.

I pass the functionName as a String to my journalService and the arguments as an array of Serializable Objects. I demand the arguments to be Serializable because I need to persist them to an external database.

I contact my database via a REST/JSON framework, so I just want to post my journal entries to my database. My problem however is this: how can I put the Serializable Objects (the args) into my JSON body? And in what format do I need to store them in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would serialize the objects to a byte array/stream, and base64-encode the array/stream to get a printable String.

At the database level, you can store the base64 string as a CLOB, or decode it to a byte array and store it as a BLOB.

Comment: I found a java package: org.quickconnect.json wich provides JSONOutputStreams and methods to convert a Serializable to exactly that. (perfect for my case) But can i store outputstream objects directly in a database?

Comment: An OutputStream doesn't contain data. It's an object used to send bytes somewhere (for example, to a byte array (ByteArrayOutputStream) or to a file (FileOutputStream)). You can write your JSON to a byte array, and store this byte array as a BLOB in the database.